# Why declare HEX rather than DECIMAL in "reginit.ini"?

Tags: windows, windows-ce

I am developing my own embedded OS based on Windows CE 6.0 Kernel, i have generated my OS runtime image and uploaded it to the emulator, then i have developed an application to launch immediately with the OS and i have used registry to launch it, in the **project.reg** file i must declare the process launch and the dependence :

```
“Launch99”=”MyApp.exe”
“Depend99”=hex:3C,00
```

when i look up in the  **"reginit.ini"** file i find :

```
“Launch20”=”device.dll”
“Launch30”=”gwes.dll”
“Depend30”=hex:14,00
“Launch50”=”explorer.exe”
“Depend50”=hex:14,00,1E,00
“Launch60”=”servicesStart.exe”
“Depend60”=hex:14,00
“Launch99”=”MyApp.exe”
“Depend99”=hex:3C,00
```

thats OK but my question is basic : why should i declare the dependence in HEX value rather than DECIMAL as the process ?

Comment: Because that's just how they designed it?  What problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/12/dont-be-afraid-to-use-the-science/

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Yes, but my curiosity expands and i must ask these questions, it is basic YES, but there is a reason for it, i know it is not gonna be a deal but i love to know why !! this is simply it bro !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, `hex values` are preferred over `decimal values` as the conversion to binary from hex involves less computation than the conversion from `decimal`.

You could see that, all the addresses are preferred to be in hexadecimal values, for easy memory accesses. That is because, they are concise to represent as byte-level. As nearly all the data, command and address transfers and registers are in bytes, this one is preferred.

Hex values simplify the representation of large numbers for programmers. Hence, hexadecimal is at the top list of preferences. It has become an unwritten rule/specification that we shall use hex values wherever possible. And hence, everything is designed based on that, including the format of `Dependxx` in `reginit.ini`